# How to access TabPages that are created in real-time?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, dynamically-generated

Some inits done earlier in the code...

```
private List<System.Windows.Forms.TabPage> tab_pages = new List<System.Windows.Forms.TabPage>();

int tab_increment = 0;
```

Somewhere in the code, I create a bunch of tab pages in real-time.

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{

    tab_pages.Add(  new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()  );

    tab_pages[tab_increment].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
    tab_pages[tab_increment].Name = 1 + tab_increment.ToString();
    tab_pages[tab_increment].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(501, 281);
    tab_pages[tab_increment].Text = tab_increment.ToString();

    this.tabControl.Controls.Add(tab_pages[tab_increment]);
    tab_increment += 1;
}
```

Now I would like to access elements that are these tab pages. Also let's pretend that I created different elements on each page (example, tabPage[0] a button, tabPage[1] a checkbox, etc), how do I access them knowing that everything was added dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this approach:

```
void Walk(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
    {
        //just walking through controls...
        //...do something

        //but remember, it could contain containers itself (say, groupbox or panel, etc.)...so, do a recursion
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
            Walk(c);

    }
    //or
    foreach (Button btn in control.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        //an example of how to walk through controls sub array of certain type
        //this loop won't have a single iteration if this page contains no Buttons

        //..so you can replace Button 
        //and have some certain code for different types of controls
    }
}
```

And launch it for tabcontrol:

```
foreach (TabPage page in tabControl1.TabPages)
    Walk(page);
```

---

I guess there is no special need to have separate collection of tabpages for one tabcontrol, as soon as it has `TabPages` property.

In the code above I used [Enumerable.OfType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)  to get a subcollection of controls of certain type.

---

As for your code, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    this.tabControl.Controls.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage());
    this.tabControl.TabPages[i].Text = i.ToString();
    //...do whatever you need
    //...
    //besdies, I think, ther's no need in tab_increment...loop index works well enough
}
```

Comment: It is definitely useful!! I feel my problem is almost solved!

Comment: I have another question, how would I use Dababinding in the current context?

Comment: @TheScholar your description "*use DataBinding in the current context*" is very broad. Definetely you should describe what you need and what you've already tried and got stuck on in greater detail. Besides this is a completely different question, and according to the format of this site you by no means expected to start another question and get a separate response there.

Answer (score 2):

In order to add pages, I think that using

```
tabControl.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("Name"));
```

or in your case

```
this.tabControl.TabPages.Add(tab_pages[tab_increment]);
```

is more suitable.

In order to access them you could use

```
TabPage tp = tabControl.TabPages[i];  //where i is the index of your TabPage
```

and you can use `TabPage.Controls.Add` of the Controls property to add any `Control` on the `TabPage` like:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Name = "Button name";
tp.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) property on the TabPage object. Each control in the collection is given to you as a [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx), and it is up to you to cast them to the type that you want.